# How to make jfree chart to take non empty series data set to plot range axis

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have multiple datasets let arrTimeSeriesCollection[10], and i am creating time series chart using first dataset ie; arrTimeSeriesCollection[0] where first dataset have values 'null' ie;series.add(time, null); but, when i am adding second dataset to chart it is not showing (second dataset had some values).  How to adjust range axis to valid dataset (which had non-null values).

```
public class MultipleDatasetDemo extends ApplicationFrame implements ActionListener 
{
  private XYPlot plot;
  private int datasetIndex = 0;
  public MultipleDatasetDemo(final String title) 
  {
    super(title);
    final TimeSeriesCollection dataset1 = createEmptyRandomDataset("Series 1");
    final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
        "Multiple Dataset Demo 1", "Time", "Value", dataset1, true, true, false
        );
    chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);

    this.plot = chart.getXYPlot();
    this.plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.lightGray);
    this.plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.white);
    this.plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);

    final ValueAxis axis = this.plot.getDomainAxis();
    axis.setAutoRange(false);

    final NumberAxis rangeAxis2 = new NumberAxis("Range Axis 2");
    rangeAxis2.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);

    final JPanel content = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

    final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
    content.add(chartPanel);

    final JButton button1 = new JButton("Add Dataset");
    button1.setActionCommand("ADD_DATASET");
    button1.addActionListener(this);

    final JButton button2 = new JButton("Remove Dataset");
    button2.setActionCommand("REMOVE_DATASET");
    button2.addActionListener(this);

    final JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    buttonPanel.add(button1);
    buttonPanel.add(button2);

    content.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 270));
    setContentPane(content);

  }

  private TimeSeriesCollection createRandomDataset(final String name) {
    final TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries(name);
    double value = 100.0;
    RegularTimePeriod t = new Day();
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
      series.add(t, value);
      t = t.next();
      value = value * (1.0 + Math.random() / 100);
    }
    return new TimeSeriesCollection(series);
  }

  private TimeSeriesCollection createEmptyRandomDataset(final String name) {
    final TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries(name);
    double value = 100.0;
    RegularTimePeriod t = new Day();
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
      series.add(t, null);
      t = t.next();
      value = value * (1.0 + Math.random() / 100);
    }
    return new TimeSeriesCollection(series);
  }

  public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {

    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("ADD_DATASET")) {
      if (this.datasetIndex < 20) {
        this.datasetIndex++;
        this.plot.setDataset(
            this.datasetIndex, createRandomDataset("S" + this.datasetIndex)
            );
        this.plot.setRenderer(this.datasetIndex, new StandardXYItemRenderer());
      }
      this.plot.getRangeAxis().setAutoRange(false);

    }
    else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("REMOVE_DATASET")) {
      if (this.datasetIndex >= 1) {
        this.plot.setDataset(this.datasetIndex, null);
        this.plot.setRenderer(this.datasetIndex, null);
        this.datasetIndex--;
      }
    }

  }

  public static void main(final String[] args) {

    final MultipleDatasetDemo demo = new MultipleDatasetDemo("Multiple Dataset Demo 1");
    demo.pack();
    RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(demo);
    demo.setVisible(true);

  }

}
```

Comment: Where is `arrTimeSeriesCollection` in this code?